# How to get Item from ItemID in JSS?

Tags: jss, sitecore-api

I am trying to understand how to fetch Item from ItemID in JSS.

What is alternative for Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(new ID("{11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111}")) in JSS?

Comment: My question is specific to JSS. I have edited the question to be more specific. May I know where should I ask this question if not here?